# Dynamics CRM Entity Data update from a custom Aspx Page

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have found many sample to create data in dynamics crm from a custom aspx page, but i need to update entity data.
any sample will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, when you create a record normally you use the following code:

```cs
Entity newContact = new Entity("contact");
contact["firstname"] = "John";
contact["lastname"] = "Smith";
service.Create(newContact);
```

If you need to update a record, you need to retrieve it first (using a `Retrieve` if you have the Guid, or a `RetrieveMultiple` if you need to find it using a query), after just update the fields.

```cs
Entity retrievedContact = service.Retrieve("contact", GuidOfTheRecord, ColumnsYouWantToRetrieve);
retrievedContact["firstname"] = "My New First Name";
retrievedContact["lastname"] = "My New Last Name";
service.Update(retrievedContact);
```

Comment: Actually I wouldn't retrieve the entity to update if you don't need to. Besides saving a round-trip, the update will fire plugins/workflows on ALL columns that you have retrieved, even if they haven't changed. If you already have the Guid and you just need to update firstname/lastname, I'd recommend this:

`retrievedContact["contactid"] = GuidOfTheRecord;
retrievedContact["firstname"] = "My New First Name";
retrievedContact["lastname"] = "My New Last Name";
service.Update(retrievedContact);`

Comment: Thanks guys, but my problem Thanks for the replay, but my problem is how to get the GUID of the record in the email, let me explain my scenario :

I have a custom entity with field named Approval, when data created a workflow is fired to send email to the approver to approve one attribute "Approval", the customer want from the email approve the Data without accessing to the CRM but he is a CRM user, that's why i want to insert in the email a link to web page (pop-up) that show him only too option (Accept or Reject) and then Update the entity attribute.

Comment: I can get the guid as parameters from the url, and i tried the code below but i get error :

string smsguidurl = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
Guid smsguid = new Guid(smsguidurl);
ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "new_testapp" });
Entity retrievedsms = service.Retrieve("new_smsmessage", smsguid, attributes);
retrievedsms["new_testapp"] = "Approved";
service.Update(retrievedsms);